# Disable hardware RAID controller

Tags: software-raid, hardware-raid, supermicro, megaraid, storage-server

I have a storage server with [Supermicro X9SCL(+)/X9SCM motherboard](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C202_C204/X9SCL-F.cfm) and MegaRAID SAS 9240-4i controller. I want to disable RAID to access HDDs directly from OS for further softraid setup.

Motherboard manual says there should 4 options: Disabled, IDE, SATA and RAID. But I see only 3:

[image: BIOS Screenshot].

I have tried IDE and SATA options, it didn't show change, Ubuntu16.04LiveCD doesn't see disks. Is possible to disable hardware RAID?

Comment: That looks like you're in the wrong section of configuration menu, that looks like a normal BIOS screen and not the RAID controller firmware, which you can typically select a bit later during startup.

Comment: I looked there too, in the WebBIOS. But I can only manage virtual drives and disk groups there, no option for disabling RAID. Maybe it's called differently, not _disable raid_ but something else?

Comment: You might have the option to select JBOD or passthrough as the RAID level which is the same, i.e. present the individual disks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible to disable or bypass this RAID, but you can configure each drive as separate JBOD/RAID0 array.
Easiest is to go to MegaRaid Cli (CRTL+Y before boot).
There you just run this command:
`-CfgEachDskRaid0 -aAll`

see:
http://ehaselwanter.com/en/blog/2012/11/26/MegaRaid-as-fake-JBOD-for-swift/

Than you should see all drives separately in OS

Answer (score 4):

You can't configure disks connected to the SAS controller in the BIOS. During system startup, there should appear a prompt for a different setup system (Ctrl+H if I remember correctly). https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Managing_an_MegaRAID_Controller

Comment: I looked there too, in the WebBIOS. But I can only manage virtual drives and disk groups there, no option for disabling RAID. Maybe it's called differently, not _disable raid_ but something else?

Comment: You need to switch them into JBOD mode (this just means passthrough as single disks). If the controller doesn't support this (and I believe the 9240 doesn't), you need to configure each disk into it's own single disk RAID0.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to disable RAID controller. Instead you can configure RAID0 with one drive. In that way create RAID0 arrays for remaining drives.
This way we can utilise all the disks.....

Comment: This isn't a supported configuration with either VMware VSAN or MSFT S2D: RAID0 doesn't eliminate RAID's firmware and referenced SDS solutions need 100% control over drive's hardware. TL;DR: You need HBA.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the guidances to flash MegaRAID SAS 9240-4i to IT firmware:

https://www.servethehome.com/ibm-serveraid-m1015-part-4/

http://brycv.com/blog/2012/flashing-it-firmware-to-lsi-sas9211-8i/